# Syntax for using Cursor to retrieve a single value from database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I need to get the ave of a column durms(Integer) which stores seconds in milliseconds.
Im trying to do that by assigning the value directly to a long variable.
Is this correct?
I checked with log.d(dur, cursor.getLong(0));

It always gives a 0.
I checked in DB and the column durms has values in it.

Please help me :) The code is as below.

```
public String getAve(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "select avg(durms) from logs where type ='" +s+ "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String dur = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    Log.d(dur, String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(0)));
    long ss = cursor.getLong(0) / 1000 % 60;
    long mm = cursor.getLong(0) / (1000 * 60) % 60;
    long hh = cursor.getLong(0) / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 60;
    if (hh > 0)
        dur = hh + "h " + mm + "m " + ss + "s ";
    else if (mm > 0)
        dur = mm + "m " + ss + "s ";
    else
        dur = ss + "s ";

    }
    return dur;

}
```

Also please tell the shortest way to retrieve a value from db for manipulation.

Thanks,
Karthick.

Comment: Likely the `where` didn't match anything and the average for 0 values is null that converts to 0 when interpreted as long.

Comment: Great sir :) I found the type value stuck among the data flow steps :)